# How to pass enum value as parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums

I'm learning C# on my own from a book and don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I have a base abstract class, `Employee`, that the class `Director` inherits from, and the class `Partner` inherits from that. I want to set the job title in the `Partner` class based on an enum type with job titles. Assume the following (MWE) code:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    protected string title = "Employee";  // underlying field

    public string Title { get { return title; } }  // read-only property

    public Employee() { // do some stuff all children need }  // constructor

    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", Title);
    }
}


public class Director : Employee
{
    protected new string title = "Director";  // shadowing field works here

    public int NumberOfProjectsManaged { get; set; }  // additional property

    public Director() : base() { NumberOfProjectsManaged = 0; } // constructor

    public override void Display()
    {
        base.Display();
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Projects Managed: {0}", NumberOfProjectsManaged);
    }
}


public class Partner : Director
{
    // there are more than two in the actual code, but this is a MWE
    public enum SpecificTitle
    {
      Principal,
      Partner
    };

    public Partner() : base() 
    {
        this._setTitle(SpecificTitle.Partner);  // defaults to Partner
    }

    public Partner(SpecificTitle jobTitle) 
    {
        this._setTitle(jobTitle);  // overloaded ctor allows user to specify
    }

    private void _setTitle(SpecificTitle jobTitle)
    {
        switch (jobTitle)
        {
            case SpecificTitle.Principal:
                this.title = "Principal";
                break;
            case SpecificTitle.Partner:
            default:
                this.title = "Partner";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Director` class works fine and the title is always "Director" as desired. However, the `Partner` class always has the title "Employee" rather than "Partner" or "Principal". It doesn't matter if I simply use the default constructor:

```
Partner DefaultTitle = new Partner();  // title = "Employee"
```

Or if I specify one:

```
Partner PrincipalTitle = new Partner(Partner.SpecificTitle.Principal);
```

To output the value, I use the inherited `Display()` method:

```
DefaultTitle.Display();
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: how did you output it? can you show us

Comment: I just updated to show how I am outputting it using the `Display()` method from the base `Employee` class. Could that be the problem? I override it in `Director`, but not in `Partner` (because I am not adding anything new to it, so it should be using the one from `Director`, right?).

Comment: I don't know why you have to define `title` again in subclass, but you don't have this problem if you remove `title` define in `Director`. The `Title` property return value of `title` in your parent class, not your `new title` in subclass.

Comment: @TrầnAnhNam please demonstrate, I'm not understanding you. I don't see how not shadowing it in Director solves the issue (that simply creates a new issue in the Director class and leaves the Partner class issue unresolved from what I can tell). Please *explain*. I'm not just looking for a solution, I want to learn/understand. This is all just code I am writing to learn, not to solve any real problems.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but your virtual display always returns the title of Employee since it always takes the initiated title on your abstract class.  No matter how you set the `title` in your `Partner` class, it only sets the `title` in the Director class.  Or did I understand your code right?

Comment: @robwaminal i have an answer, check if this solution is OK with you, I don't care if you downvote it :) I'm just happy that I solved it.

Comment: You wrote `Title` property in `Employee`, so it returns values of `Employee.title`, if you shadow `title` in subclass, `Title` property will not returns that subclass `title`, you have to override it to return new `title` value.

Comment: @TrầnAnhNam that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of this line:

```
protected new string title = "Director";
```

The `new` keyword is hiding the `Employee` definition of `title`.

Not really a problem if that is what you are wanting. The problem comes in when you are calling `Partner.Display` the path of execution traces back to the `Employee` definition of that method. Which in the `Employee` definition it is using the hidden `title` field.

When you are setting the `title` in the `Partner` class you are only setting the `new` `title` field in the `Director` class and not the base class `Employee`'s `title` field.

To fix this issue remove the line in question *mentioned above*. Then you will want to make your `Director` constructor look like this.

```
public Director() : base() 
{ 
    NumberOfProjectsManaged = 0; 
    title = "Director";
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't Display trace back to the Director class? Why does it skip over that back to Employee class? Sorry, genuinely trying to understand.

Comment: @BobDylan it doesn't skip over it. It calls the 'Director' override but that override calls the 'Employee' version.

Comment: OK, this makes sense. Now the trick is how to do this so that I don't have to set the title in every constructor. The real Employee class has two constructors and I don't want user to be able to set any title they want so I need to protect that constructor. And Director has 8+ constructors. I see no way to get around manually defining title in all of them.

Comment: This is another question, though. Torn between marking your answer as accepted and wablab's, both are helpful.

Comment: I marked this as accepted. I now have more problems than what I started with, but I know *why*, which is the most important thing! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The base `Employee.Display()` method prints the value of its `title` field. The `Director` class defines a `new title` field, which shadows (not overrides) the base `Employee.title` field. The `Partner` and `Director` class work with `Director.title`, which has nothing to do with the base `Employee.title` field. Refactor your `Director` class to remove the `new title` field.

Comment: exactly what I'm thinking

Comment: OK, could you explain a little more? Wouldn't it display "Director", not "Employee" if Partner really worked with Director.title?

Comment: The reason I shadowed it is because the actual Director class has over 8 constructors, and I didn't want to have to set title="Director" in all of them. But I suppose how to do that better is another question then if this works. But please explain further - I don't understand *why* this answer is correct.

Comment: Perhaps provide a protected constructor in the Employee class that accepts a value for title. Your derived classes can pass the appropriate value to it. The non-default Director constructors could call `this()` instead of `base()`, and the default Director constructor could be the only one which calls `base("Director")`

Comment: Is there a way to then not have to pass a title in every single constructor, though? (PS +1 from me, and I will accept this once it finally all makes sense, pardon my difficulty understanding).

Comment: See my revised comment above for an approach on this.

Comment: @wablab I will try to do that to see if I am understanding correctly and will mark accepted if this works.

Comment: @MattRowland's answer does a good job of explaining how the `new` keyword is hiding the `title` field, leading to `Director` and derived classes setting a field that the base `Employee` class can't "see".

Answer (score 1):

It would appear as if you problem is in the Director class, in particular the following line:

```
protected new string title = "Director";  // shadowing field works here
```

You don't really need it, and you may also want to change your constructor as well. Heres the Director class

```
public class Director : Employee
{
    //protected string title = "Director";  // shadowing field works here

    public int NumberOfProjectsManaged { get; set; }  // additional property

    public Director() : base() {
        NumberOfProjectsManaged = 0;
        title = "Director";
    } // constructor

    public override void Display()
    {
        base.Display();
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Projects Managed: {0}", NumberOfProjectsManaged);
    }
}
```

For testing I used this:

```
Partner DefaultTitle = new Partner();
DefaultTitle.Display();
Partner PrincipalTitle = new Partner(Partner.SpecificTitle.Principal);
PrincipalTitle.Display();
Director director = new Director();
director.Display();
```

and got the following output:

```
Title: Partner
Number of Projects Managed: 0
Title: Principal
Number of Projects Managed: 0
Title: Director
Number of Projects Managed: 0
```

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't explain why this affects the code.

Comment: What in particular are you confused about?

Comment: OK, I see kind of. What I'm confused about is why it says "Employee" rather than "Director". I shadowed it to avoid having to put title="Director" in about 8+ constructors (the actual class has a lot of constructors). Is there a better way to do that? I'm trying to understand why it defaulted back to "Employee" rather than "Director" in the Partner class.

Comment: You say "problem is in the Director class" and "You don't really need it". Which is true. But you don't say _what the problem is_ or _why the problem occurs_.

Comment: @BobDylan are you talking about having a second constructor, something like this `public Director(int numberOfProjectsManaged) : this() { NumberOfProjectsManaged = numberOfProjectsManaged; } // constructor 2` ? this call call the default Director constructor first then do the code in the second constructor

Comment: also since `NumberOfProjectsManaged` is an int, it will always be defaulted to 0

Answer (score 1):

To cater your need not to define title in all of the constructors in your Director class

```
public Director() : base() {
    // other stuffs
    this.title = "Director";
}

// other constuctors
public Director(object someparam) : this() {
    // do some stuff
}
```

So every time a constructor is called, it bubbles up to the base constructor.

Comment: poor me thats ok :3

Answer (score 0):

You can set the enum 'SpecificTitle' ouside from Partner class.

```
public enum SpecificTitle
{
   Principal,
   Partner
};
```

and use the type of title in both Employee and Director classes as 'SpecificTitle' enum

```
public abstract class Employee
{
   protected SpecificTitle title = "Employee";
   //others
}


 public class Director : Employee
 {
   protected SpecificTitle title = "Director";
   //others
 }
```

and replace the switch case as the following:

```
switch (jobTitle)
{
  case SpecificTitle.Principal:
    this.title = SpecificTitle.Principal;
    break;
  case SpecificTitle.Partner:
  default:
    this.title = SpecificTitle.Partner;
    break;
}
```

or sure you should replace the switch case with this line

```
private void _setTitle(SpecificTitle jobTitle)
{
    this.title = jobTitle;
}
```

I did not tested this, but this logic will work with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Partner DefaultTitle = new Partner();  // title = "Employee"
            DefaultTitle.Display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public virtual string title { get; set; }  // underlying field

      public string Title
      {
          get { return title; }
      }  // read-only property

      public Employee() { // do some stuff all children need 
          this.title = "Employee";
      }  // constructor

      public virtual void Display()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", Title);
      }
    }


    public class Director : Employee
    {
      public override string title { get; set; }  // shadowing field works here

      public int NumberOfProjectsManaged { get; set; }  // additional property

      public Director() : base() {
          this.title = "Director";
      } // constructor

      public override void Display()
      {
        base.Display();
      }
    }


    public class Partner : Director
    {
      // there are more than two in the actual code, but this is a MWE
      public override string title { get; set; }
      public enum SpecificTitle
      {
        Principal,
        Partner
      };

      public Partner() : base() 
      {
        this._setTitle(SpecificTitle.Partner);  // defaults to Partner
      }

      public Partner(SpecificTitle jobTitle) 
      {
        this._setTitle(jobTitle);  // overloaded ctor allows user to specify
      }

      private void _setTitle(SpecificTitle jobTitle)
      {
        switch (jobTitle)
        {
          case SpecificTitle.Principal:
            this.title = "Principal";
            break;
          case SpecificTitle.Partner:
          default:
            this.title = "Partner";
            break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Finally got it working! sorry for my last answer. I set the base class to virtual so any child classes can overwrite its value.

[C# virtual reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

robwaminal is correct, setting the title in `Partner` class only set the title of it's direct parent which is `Director`.

Comment: your Title property in your abstract Employee has a setter, you can take that out if you really want it to be a `readonly` property

Comment: @robwaminal sorry I forgot to remove it thanks, Im just a little bit excited.

Comment: It doesn't let me override a string field. I get an error. You seem to be mixing up fields and properties. The whole point of keeping title as a field is to keep it protected (in the family) and not let outside assemblies nor classes use it.

Comment: @BobDylan what is the error? the code i added is running fine. So if its that the case then, why are you planning to set its value in derived classes :3